# Super Tricky Javascript quiz, need to figure out about the answer

Tags: javascript

```
   //1st question
   var x = 4,
     obj = {
       x: 3,
       bar: function() {
         var x = 2;
         setTimeout(function() {
           var x = 1;
           alert(this.x);
         }, 1000);
       }
     };
   obj.bar();

   //2nd question
   function foo(a) {
     arguments[0] = 2;
     alert(a);
   }
   foo(1);
```

1.why it returns 4 instead of 1? i thought this.x refer to 1, but it seems wrong....i just dont understand why it returns 4

2.why it return alert 2 instead of 1, i thought i pass a to function a, and as far as i know, i pass 1 to function foo, and 1 should be alerted because of a(which is 1 when i pass)....i just don't understand why it alert 2

Comment: console.log `this` and you will see that it is referring to the window. on that level x has been defined as 4. This is all about scoping. check out this article, especially the part about `this` inside of closures ;)  http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The runtime (in non-strict mode) invokes the `setTimeout()` callback with `this` bound to `window` (the global context), so `this.x` refers to the outer `x`.
2. The `arguments` object serves as a way to alias the formal parameters of a function. Setting the value of `arguments[0]` also sets the value of the first declared parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

*1. why it returns 4 instead of 1?*

Notice the first initialization: `var x = 4`, which in non-strict mode attaches a property `x` to global object: `window.x = 4`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
 var x = 1;
 alert(this.x);
}, 1000);
```

`setTimout()` callback has `this` context as the global object. And actually calling `alert(this.x)` -> `alert(window.x)` -> `alert(4)`.

*2.why it return alert 2 instead of 1*

`arguments` object represents the list of function arguments. When modifying it, you actually modify the arguments values: `arguments[0] = 2` modifies first argument `a = 2`.